# Extracting data from JSON with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Probably a stupid issue, but I am stuck.

I have a node.js server that sends data to a client, like this:

```
var message_to_client = result;
socket.send(JSON.stringify(message_to_client));
```

Client succesfully receives the data; if I log it on console, it reads like this:

```
[{"_id":"55e60d3de4b06ef3ed5f189e","par1":54.2441033, "par2":-10.177503399999999}]
```

I want to show the par1 value on screen, however I don't seem to be able to 'extract' it from the JSON response.

I tried with the parseJSON function from jQuery and with https://stackoverflow.com/a/22628619/3849735, neither worked.

Anyone can help? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by **neither worked** ? What are the errors you are getting ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send the response in json format instead in string, like

```
var message_to_client = result;
socket.send(message_to_client);
```

client side

```
 data[0].par1
```

will return the values

Comment: Done that, printing data gives me Object object, printing data.par1 gives undefined

Comment: client side `data[0].par1`  will return values